# Converting array of enum values to flags enum

Tags: c#, arrays, enums

I am trying to implement functionality in a way that it was specified here:

[Specific solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616775/convert-array-of-enum-values-to-bit-flag-combination)

However, I'm trying to do it as generic method to be used as an extension:

```
    public static TEnum? Merge<TEnum>(this IEnumerable<TEnum> values)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IComparable, IFormattable
    {
        Nullable<TEnum> merged = null;
        if (values == null || values.Count() == 0)
            return null;

        foreach(TEnum value in values)
        {
            if (merged == null)
                merged = value;
            else
            {
                merged = merged | value;
            }
        }
        return merged;
    }
```

Problem is however that this line:

```
merged = merged | value;
```

Will not compile. Message I'm getting is:

**Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TEnum?' and 'TEnum'.**

Is it possible to write this generic method that will convert array of enum values to flags enum?

Comment: Why would you need to return `TEnum?` here? A `[Flags]` enum should *always* have a `0`/`None` value - wouldn't you just return that?

Comment: Aside: doing a `Count()` on the sequence means you are iterating it twice - that is not a good idea - it could be expensive, but is not even guaranteed to work

Comment: There's no *simple* way of doing this that doesn't involve boxing; would complicated approaches suffice?

Comment: I am trying to merge array of enum values into one enum value that is made of those values, under condition that TEnum is enum marked with [FlagsEnum]. Do I make any sense here? :) Check the link on other stackoverflow thread, I'm trying to accomplish the same in a generic way.

Comment: The problem is once you enter the domain of generics, the behaviour of `Enum` is effectively lost therefore you can't simply OR the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here, but the biggest is that generics *does not support operators* - and `|` is an operator. You can hack around it via `object`, but then you have boxing. Here's what I would do - it generates some dynamic IL per-enum-type (once only), and uses that to do a direct "or" without boxing. Note that it also uses `0` for the default return (far more expected, IMO), and avoids an explicit `Count()`, as that can be unpredictably expensive, and can break the enumerator (you can't guarantee that you can enumerate data more than once):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public static class EnumUtils
{
    public static TEnum Merge<TEnum>(this IEnumerable<TEnum> values)
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        TEnum merged = default(TEnum);
        if (values != null)
        {
            var or = Operator<TEnum>.Or;
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                merged = or(merged, value);
            }
        }
        return (TEnum)(object)merged;
    }
    static class Operator<T>
    {
        public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Or;

        static Operator()
        {
            var dn = new DynamicMethod("or", typeof(T),
                new[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) }, typeof(EnumUtils));
            var il = dn.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Or);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            Or = (Func<T, T, T>)dn.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, T, T>));
        }

    }
}
static class Program {

    [Flags]
    public enum Foo
    {
        None = 0, A = 1,  B =2, C = 4
    }
    static unsafe void Main()
    {
        var merged = EnumUtils.Merge(new[] { Foo.A, Foo.C });

    }
}
```

---

Edit: if you *really must* return `null` for the "null or empty" case, then you could use the following tweak - but I emphasize: IMO this is an *incorrect* implementation - it would be more correct to simply return `0` (aka `default(TEnum)`) for this scenario.

```
public static TEnum? Merge<TEnum>(this IEnumerable<TEnum> values)
    where TEnum : struct
{
    if (values == null) return null;
    using (var iter = values.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iter.MoveNext()) return null;
        TEnum merged = iter.Current;
        var or = Operator<TEnum>.Or;
        while(iter.MoveNext())
        {
            merged = or(merged, iter.Current);
        }
        return merged;
    }
}
```

What this does is:

- check for a null sequence, short-circuit
- obtain the sequence iterator, and try to read a value - short-circuit if none
- use the current (first) value as our seed, and obtain the operator
- iterate the sequence, applying the operator successively
- return the combined value

Comment: Can you just adjust method to return TEnum? Defalt(TEnum) is not really working for me. Apart from that, I'm new to DynamicMethod concept, so it will take me some time to understand what you just did :)

Comment: `default(TEnum)`, with a small `d`, is a reserved C# keyword - that should work fine, even for generics. What I did was use the fact that static constructors are only evaluated once, hence the static constructor for `Operator<T>` is executed once per unique `T`. So inside the static constructor, we create a runtime method that declares 2 parameters, reads them onto the stack, applies "or" (fortunately, an IL operator exists), and returns the value - and store a typed delegate to that method in the `Or` field. Then in our  `Merge` method, we obtain that delegate and execute it per item.

Comment: @BarisaPuter to be clear: `default(TEnum)` is really just a way of saying "zero out enough memory for a `TEnum`, and give me the value" - which is, as it happens, exactly what we want for an enum value without any flags set.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a typo :) I'm familiar with default(TEnum), I'm just trying to have method that will build a valid enum value from flags, or just return null instead if i.e. values collection supplied as input is null or empty collection.

Comment: @BarisaPuter frankly, I think the "else return null" is a bad and confusing idea, but I'll add an edit to show that

Comment: Thank you, you've saved me quite a lot of headache + this is something really new to me and I like it ;)

Comment: Today, the Linq method is short enough so that there's no need for an extension method any more, although this is also possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66414362/2505186

Answer (score 3):

**1 line in Linq, no need for a helper method:**

```
var result = enumArray.Aggregate ((TestEnum)0, (a, b) => a | b);
```

**But if you don't want to remember this code, an extension method is also possible:**

```
private static T Merge<T> (this T[] i_enumValues)
// - or -
// private static T Merge<T> (params T[] i_enumValues)
  where T : Enum
{
  var type = typeof (T);
  if (!type.IsDefined (typeof (FlagsAttribute), false))
    throw new ArgumentException ($"The given enum type '{type}' does not have the {nameof (FlagsAttribute)}.");

  var zero = (T)Convert.ChangeType (0, Enum.GetUnderlyingType (type));

  var result = i_enumValues.Aggregate (zero, (a, b) => (dynamic)a | (dynamic)b);

  return result;
}
```

**Proof of concept:**

```
[Flags]
public enum TestEnum : ulong
{
  First  = 1   << 0,
  Second = 1   << 1,
  Third  = 1   << 2,
  Fourth = 1   << 3,
  Fifth  = 1   << 4,
  Bit40  = 1ul << 40
}

private static void Main (string[] args)
{
  var enumArray = new[] { TestEnum.First, TestEnum.Second, TestEnum.Third, TestEnum.Bit40 };
  var result    = enumArray.Aggregate ((TestEnum)0, (a, b) => a | b);
  var result2   = Merge (enumArray);
}
```

Output:

```
result  = First | Second | Third | Bit40
result2 = First | Second | Third | Bit40
result .ToString ("X") -> "0000010000000007"
result2.ToString ("X") -> "0000010000000007"
```

Comment: Nice answer. Strange though that you wrote an extension method and did not use the related syntax `enumArray.Merge()`.

Comment: @Askolein: See my edits of the answer. The method was a `private static T Merge<T> (params T[] i_enumValues)` first. I just did not update the example.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this ability and was glad to find Marc's answer. I took a stab at using some newer language features. Here's what I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Intended for merging an enumeration of flags enum into a single value.
    /// </summary>
    public static TEnum Merge<TEnum>(this IEnumerable<TEnum> values)
        where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var type = typeof(TEnum);
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{type} is not an enum type.");

        return values.DefaultIfEmpty(default(TEnum)).Aggregate(Operator<TEnum>.Or);
    }

    static class Operator<T>
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<Func<T, T, T>> LazyOr;
        private static readonly Lazy<Func<T, T, T>> LazyAnd;

        public static Func<T, T, T> Or => LazyOr.Value;
        public static Func<T, T, T> And => LazyAnd.Value;

        static Operator()
        {
            var enumType = typeof(T);
            var underType = enumType.GetEnumUnderlyingType();
            var leftParam = Expression.Parameter(enumType, "left");
            var rightParam = Expression.Parameter(enumType, "right");
            var leftCast = Expression.ConvertChecked(leftParam, underType);
            var rightCast = Expression.ConvertChecked(rightParam, underType);

            Lazy<Func<T, T, T>> CreateLazyOp(Func<Expression, Expression, BinaryExpression> opFunc) =>
            new Lazy<Func<T, T, T>>(() =>
            {
                var op = opFunc(leftCast, rightCast);
                var resultCast = Expression.ConvertChecked(op, enumType);
                var l = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(resultCast, leftParam, rightParam);
                return l.Compile();
            });

            LazyOr = CreateLazyOp(Expression.Or);
            LazyAnd = CreateLazyOp(Expression.And);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's muuuuch easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66414362/2505186